# Deployed SSIS package Oracle Connection Manager erroring with "Access is denied." OLE DB error code 0x80070005

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-2019

Still pretty green to SSIS development and struggling with a current hurdle.

I have a rather basic SSIS package that reads data from an Excel sheet stored on a File Share, and pending a [Lookup] result with an Oracle Connection Manager, either Updates existing data with rows from file or inserts new rows.

Everything runs fine as expected in Visual Studio, authored as my personal user with Project and all Packages secured as *ProtectionLevel: EncrypSensitiveWithUserKey*. As somewhat expected after deploying, NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT does not have contextual access to the File Share like my personal user, so a Proxy account has been setup and given folder security access on the File Share.

The proxy successfully completes the task of reading data from the Excel File on the File Share, but, on the second step "Data Flow Task" fails with the following errors:

- Data Row Task: Error: Lookup - Check for Records existing in DB failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.
- Data Flow Task: Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER. The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "XXXXXX (OLE DB)" failed with error code 0xC0202009. There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the Acquire Connection method call failed.
- {Package}: Error. SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80070005. An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Service Components" Hresult: 0x80070005 Description: "Access is denied."

Things I have tried:

- Both machines appear to be 64-bit but I tried configuring the Job Step under Advanced to force-execute as 32-bit when the new job calls the package. This resulted in it complaining the 32-bit is not installed/does not exist, so I changed back.
- After reading through numerous threads, it appears *ProtectionLevel: EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey* is **not** (?) the correct setting, as I want multiple team members to be able to access, execute, and configure these packages including potentially the SQLServerAgent (when feasible) or this new Proxy Account. To that end I tried two things:
- - Changed the Project and all Packages to *DontSaveSensitive*, but this resulted in my package failing even in Visual Studio running as my personal user when tested.
- - Changed the Project and all Packages to *EncrypSensitiveWithPassword* and my test execution worked fine in Visual Studio, but upon right-click --> Deploying the package to SQL Server, continues to fail with this *Access is denied.* error.

Proxy Account appears correct having:

- both *[X] public, [X] sysadmin* roles checked
- Active to both *[X] Operating system (CmdExec), [X] SQL Server Integration Services Package* subsystems (SSIS Package Execution proxy).
- Has *[X] Grant* permissions all the way down through my Integration Services Catalog node structure from SSISDB down through the Project.

What am I missing? Can any experts advise on how to correctly configure this to be working?

Comment: Could be an issue with the package password when you deploy it, or in the job (assuming you are running it from a SQL Agent job). I was having a similar issue recently, the job was created before a package password was added. So we had to repoint to the package in the job to get the password prompt.

Comment: @JakeMunson - Correct, I have deployed the package, and configured a new "SQL Server Agent" Job to run utilizing a proxy account with access to the file share to get the Excel File. What did you do to "re-point" the job? After deploying the package anew with "EncryptSensitiveWithPassword" I removed the Package from the Job Step and re-added -- receiving no password prompt?

Comment: I will be honest, I'm working with a DBA for this, he setup the job for me. I asked him and he said, "open the job step that executes the package, then click on the Data sources tab within that step and Agent will prompt for the package password."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just filling in for any others that may come across similar issue - the solution had nothing to do with ProtectionLevels which I now know to be more Package/Repo side than anything with deployment. In my case the solution ended up being exactly what the vague error message was talking about. The proxy user in my SSIS package had the right credentials, access to the source file, etc.

Where it was bombing on the [Lookup] and failing to make an Oracle Connection to check for existing records was due to the AD-Proxy User not having folder level permission to the C:\Oracle folder with TNSNAMES.ora and sub-folders with the Oracle Clients;

> "Access is denied."

Once all sub-folders and items of C:\Oracle were configured to inherit from parent and permissions granted to Read, Write, AND MODIFY - absolutely needed Modify permissions for this to work - everything started working as expected.

Appreciate all the help and advice from those above who assisted in looking into this.